# R Shiny: Displays all tests at once after checking the checkboxes

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, printing, output

I am trying to make a R Shiny App, which will print 3 statistical tests simultaneous, after the checkboxes were selected.
The problem is the app is printing just one output, and the other ones "are not founded".[Like can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfyeR.png)

I tried with

```
if(input$Stattest=='PP' | input$Stattest==1)
```

but..it doesn't work.

My code is:

```
 output$Stattest = renderUI({
     checkboxGroupInput("Stattest", "Choose test for stationarity", choices = c("ADF","PP","KPSS-TREND"))
  })
adf <- reactive({
    if(is.na(input$Stattest)){
      return(NULL)}

     if(input$Stattest=='ADF'){
       d=list()
       c=list(df_sel()[[print(input$y)]],df_sel()[[print(input$x1)]],df_sel()[[print(input$x2)]])
       for (i in 1:3){
         d[[i]]=adf.test(c[[i]])
       }
           }
    d
    })

  output$ADF=renderPrint({
    adf()
  })

 pp <- reactive({

    if(is.na(input$Stattest)){
      return(NULL)}

    if(input$Stattest=='PP' | input$Stattest==1){
      ptest=list()
      d=list(df_sel()[[print(input$y)]],df_sel()[[print(input$x1)]],df_sel()[[print(input$x2)]])
      for (i in 1:3){
        ptest[[i]]=pp.test(d[[i]])
      }

    }
    ptest
  })


  output$PP=renderPrint({
    pp()
  })
```

The main "problem" is that I need to create this `reactive` functions, because all of these tests will be printed in a pdf-report.
Any idea how could I make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `c` and associated  'test variable names' reactive expressions, perform needed tests, pull all that into a final list, then display to UI depending on user input:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput(outputId = "Stattest"), 
  
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "test_result")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Stattest = renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = "stat_test", 
      label = "Stat test:", 
      choices = c("ADF","PP","KPSS-TREND")
    )
  })
  
  # Since `df_sel()` is reactive, so should `c` be: 
  
  # <-- adf.test -->
  cc <- reactive({
    list(df_sel()[[input$y]], df_sel()[[input$x1]], 
         df_sel()[[input$x2]]) |> 
      lapply(FUN = adf.test)
  })
  
  # <-- pp.test -->
  dd <- reactive({
    list(df_sel()[[input$y]], df_sel()[[input$x1]], 
          df_sel()[[input$x2]]) |> 
      lapply(FUN = pp.test)
  })
  
  # <-- kpss-trend -->
  # ee <- reactive({
  #   list(subset_as_required) |> 
  #     lapply(FUN = your_kpss_trend_function)
  # })
  
  # <-- Final results -->
  all_results <- reactive({
    list(ADF = cc(), PP = dd(), "KPSS-TREND" = ee())
  })
  
  output$test_result <- renderPrint({
    for (test in input$stat_test) {
      print(all_results()[test])
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! The problem is that if I use ```selectInput()```, in the pdf-report it will be printed only the test which was selected (e.g. if ADF is in selectInput, in report only ADF will be printed) and I can not call ```cc()``` directly in report. I tried to make a reactive function named test_stat and then to print all in an output$, but neither in that case, I can not call the ```cc()```. what should I do?

Comment: I've made an edit to the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you again! But....I don't think I explained very well, sorry....So the main idea is that I need to print the ADF and PP test (and KPSS) on the pdf-report, but with this switch function, only the function selected in ```selectInput```, will be printed in the report. Even if in the app  the tests will be printed one at the time, in report I need to be all three simultaneous printed. Sorry for this misunderstanding.

Comment: No :( the error is ```Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable```. I even tried with ```[[```.

Comment: Corrected. Had put `all_results` instead of `all_results()`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, you are a genius!! I have one more question, sorry....if I don't select an x2 ```input$x2``` will be NULL, how can I run the tests? Unfortunately, it doesn't work if the ```input$x2``` is not select (is not a variable). The error is ```Error in .subset2: attempt to select less than one element in get1index```. I tried to set it to be 0, but nothing.....Thank you in advanced!

Comment: An `if else` statement would do. For `adf.test` it'd be something like:
`
# <-- adf.test -->
cc <- reactive({
  if (is.null(input$x2)) {
    # <-- expression to return -->
  }else{
    list(df_sel()[[input$y]], df_sel()[[input$x1]], 
         df_sel()[[input$x2]]) |> 
      lapply(FUN = adf.test)
  }
})
`

Comment: Thank you!! I will ask another question, and if you would like to help.....Is about this part of code and how could I print some comments :). Thank you again